# average background colors of classes

Tags: html, css

I have a multiple div elements with one to three classes.

```
<div class="c1 c3">elem 1</div>
<div class="c1">elem 2</div>
<div class="c1 c2 c3">elem 3</div>
<div class="c1 c2">elem 4</div>
```

via css I assign background colors

```
.c1 { background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); }
.c2 { background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); }
.c3 { background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255); }
```

as css works casscading, the last stated class determines the background color. Is it somehow possible to combine all three classes, e.g. to calculate an intersection color?
I am thinking of this result:

```
elem 1 | rgb(128, 0, 128)
elem 2 | rgb(255, 0, 0)
elem 3 | rgb(85, 85, 85)
elem 4 | rgb(128, 128, 0)
```

Comment: Not with CSS...and I'm not clear on a use case for this.

Comment: wont mind to use jquery or something else if required.. problem is I'm getting my rgb values from a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly like you want, but you can try rgba colors and pseudo-elements:

```css
.c2, .c3 {
  position: relative;
}
.c2:before, .c3:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.c1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
.c2:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}
.c3:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="c1 c3">elem 1</div>
<div class="c1">elem 2</div>
<div class="c1 c2 c3">elem 3</div>
<div class="c1 c2">elem 4</div>
```